# Get the content of a button from onclick=function()

Tags: javascript, php, html

how can I access the content of a button?

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit"  name="delete" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" onclick="deleletconfig('.$test[0].')">delete</button>
</form>
```

and this is the PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']))
    echo $_POST['delete'];
```

I need to have the result of `"deleletconfig('.$test[0].')"` in the php code.

Comment: Please read about the fundamentals of php, html and javascript. There is so much to explain - that's beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: That's not how things work.  Onclick will fire a javascript function when the button is clicked.  But your html is broken, also - you can't get the value of `$test` like that - needs to be wrapped in an echo: `onclick="deletetconfig(<?php echo $test[0]; ?>)"`

Comment: it is already in a bigger echo

Comment: Is he trying to obtain a content of a button element?

Comment: but the problem is that all of it is in wile loop

Comment: so i can't know the id of the clicked button

Comment: Combine cale_b and dognose comments. Assuming deleleteconfig() is a js function, you should be able to grab whatever you echo(keyword) into the function as a parameter. So if I were to call... boom("hello") and that led to function boom(greeting){ }, one would assume that inside the boom function, you would now have "hello" in the variable 'greeting' but only inside the function. Rethink the logic man. I get what you are doing, just go through it again.

Comment: echo '<button type="submit"  name="delete" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" onclick="deleletconfig('.$test[0].')">delete</button>' that is what i meant

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you want to provide more inforamtion (especially code).

Answer (score 0):

open the tags

```
onclick="deleletconfig('<?php echo $test[0]; ?>')"
```